# Converting flat array to tree

Tags: php, arrays, tree

I have the following array:

```
array (size=543)
  0 => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string '3' (length=1)
      1 => string '1' (length=1)
      2 => string 'a' (length=1)
  1 => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string '5' (length=1)
      1 => string '3' (length=1)
      2 => string 'a' (length=1)
  2 => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string '6' (length=1)
      1 => string '3' (length=1)
      2 => string 'a' (length=1)
  3 => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string '8' (length=1)
      1 => string '3' (length=1)
      2 => string 'a' (length=1)
  4 => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string '9' (length=1)
      1 => string '3' (length=1)
      2 => string 'a' (length=1)
  5 => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string '10' (length=2)
      1 => string '3' (length=1)
      2 => string 'a' (length=1)
  6 => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string '11' (length=2)
      1 => string '3' (length=1)
      2 => string 'a' (length=1)
  7 => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string '12' (length=2)
      1 => string '3' (length=1)
      2 => string 'a' (length=1)
  8 => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string '14' (length=2)
      1 => string '3' (length=1)
      2 => string 'a' (length=1)
```

How can I convert this array to the "tree array", so that I can generate HTML ul list out of this? I've been thinking about using the following function:

```
function generatePageTree($datas, $parent = 0, $depth = 0){
    if($depth > 1000) return ''; // Make sure not to have an endless recursion
    $tree = '';
    for($i=1, $ni=count($datas); $i < $ni - 1; $i++){
        if($datas[$i][1] == $parent){
            $tree .= str_repeat('-', $depth);
            $tree .= 'fsdfdsdf' . '<br/>';
            $tree .= $this->generatePageTree($datas, $datas[$i][0], $depth+1);
        }
    }
    return $tree;
}
```

But it generates empty array...What's wrong, how can I do this? Thanks!

So I should get something like:

```
array(size=543)
  0 =>
    array(size=2)
      0 => string '1'
      1 => array(size=2)
        0 => string '2'
```

Comment: What data structure should you be getting from your input data if the function worked?

Comment: The one so that I can generate nested ul list. Let me edit the post.